# Query MySQL And Write Results To Screen

Tags: php, mysql

I have just set-up `LAMP` and am trying to query a `mysql` database and write the results on screen.  The issue I have is that instead of writing the results of my query onscreen, my syntax is written on screen instead?

What is the proper way of querying a mysql database with php and writing the results on screen?

This is my syntax that does not work?

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "username";
  $password = "password";
  $dbname = "database";
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  if ($conn->connect_error) 
  {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 

  $sql = "Select state from PHPTests.state";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
  {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        echo $row['state'];
    }
  } 
  else 
  {
    echo "0 results";
  }
  $conn->close();
?>  
<html>
    <body>
      <h4>Hello - This is test site with php</h4>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `echo $row[state];` quote that => `echo $row['state'];` - http://www.php.net/mysqli_error - http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php `undefined constant state...`

Comment: Does it output the actual PHP code? Are you accessing the site/script through the web server (http://localhost/file.php), some mistakingly think you can right-click - open it directly from the file browser (file://c/somedir/project/file.php)

Comment: @JimL - yes I am accessing it by localhost/phptest.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- -- fixing that typo still same result.

Comment: Did you follow some guide to setup lamp? It seems like there's a problem with the apache/php setup

Comment: anything from error reporting and error checking for MySQL?

Comment: @JimL - yes I followed the guide to install apache/php.  I can execute phpinfo() in my browser with no issue.

Comment: Is `select state from PHPTests.state` a valid statement? I mean, _is `PHPTests.state` a **table**?_

Comment: @Fred-ii- the results from /var/log/apache2/error.log is blank, is that the log you were referencing?

Comment: @PerlDog - Yes, if I execute this syntax in MySQL Workbench it returns the 3 states listed in the table.

Comment: Ok, so you have a table `\`state\`` and that contains a column also called `\`state\``, right? BTW: @Fred-ii- means `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

Comment: @PerlDog - correct.  Absolutely dreadful set-up I understand, I *thought* for testing it would make it easier.

Comment: @FatBaby syntax and query errors shouldn't matter any way - you still shouldn't get the source code dumped to the screen. Is it plain black text on white background? Is it the entire source of that page?

Comment: No no, @FatBaby, I wasn't telling that. Just asking and wanted to make sure.

Comment: @JimL - I just updated my post to show full source code.  The text renders perfectly, but the php portion of it is just displayed on screen.

Comment: But if you swap out the PHP code you've got there with `phpinfo();` then the info screen renders correctly? I'm sorry for throwing out lots of questions without really getting anywhere. I'm just a bit confused by what's wrong here.

Comment: Shouldn't the PHP stuff be located whithin the body tags?

Comment: @JimL - correct, if I run the phpinfo() syntax it produces the desired output.  This syntax will not render properly.

Comment: @PerlDog small parts of it should be, but it's not relevant for the problem.

Comment: @JimL Okaayyy. I'm not a PHP guy, but I thought that code would render to the source code followed by `<html>....</html>`. How does PHP know where to put its output?

Comment: @PerlDog The problem OP is having is that the actual PHP source code is being dumped to the screen, which shouldn't happen no matter what syntax errors or whatnot is there. It seems like the PHP isn't parsed at all - but output as normal HTML. PHP will output what you want - where you want it. In the case of the code above it would produce invalid HTML, but it should still work

Comment: Thanks, @JimL, now I got it. So it seems the PHP command isn't even invoked and apache simply serves the file as-is.

Comment: @JimL - any thoughts on what could be causing the browser to just render the syntax on screen?

Comment: @FatBaby sadly no. I'm tempted to recommend you fire up a dev environment in a VM - it just feels like a waste of time spending this much time on something that's probably just some small config error og bug somewhere. https://box.scotch.io/